# how append extra alias with some servers on particular words in authorization file in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, perl

In a authorization file having some defined servers of fields but they can differ from line to line. All I want to do is to add extra alias on particular field in that line.

Need to add below extra alias after that ip(`156.154.18.6`) address:

```
|ser6.nam.net|156.154.18.7|ser7.nam.net|156.154.18.8
```

**Authorization file before:**

```
Keys fid@ser1.pub
Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser1.nam.net|156.154.12.1"

Keys fid1@ser2.pub
Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser2.nam.net|156.154.15.2|ser5.nam.net|156.154.18.6"

keys fid2@ser3.pub

Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser3.nam.net|156.154.17.4|ser5.nam.net|156.154.18.6"

keys fid3@ser4.pub
Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser4.nam.net|156.154.15.6"
```

**Authorization file after:**

```
Keys fid@ser1.pub
Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser1.nam.net|156.154.12.1"

Keys fid1@ser2.pub
Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser2.nam.net|156.154.15.2|ser5.nam.net|156.154.18.6|ser6.nam.net|156.154.18.7|ser7.nam.net|156.154.18.8"

keys fid2@ser3.pub

Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser3.nam.net|156.154.17.4|ser5.nam.net|156.154.18.6|ser6.nam.net|156.154.18.7|ser7.nam.net|156.154.18.8"

keys fid3@ser4.pub
Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser4.nam.net|156.154.15.6"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply with **`sed`** command:

```
sed 's/156\.154\.18\.6/&|ser6.nam.net|156.154.18.7|ser7.nam.net|156.154.18.8/' file
```

---

To perform substitution only on a line with `ser2.nam.net` - use the following one:

```
sed '/ser2\.nam\.net/ s/156\.154\.18\.6/&|ser6.nam.net|156.154.18.7|ser7.nam.net|156.154.18.8/' file
```

Comment: **Is that possible grep with only on first entry ser2.nam.net update like below**
_-------------------------------_
   Keys fid1@ser2.pub
    Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="**ser2.nam.net**|156.154.15.2|ser5.nam.net|156.154.18.6"



 Keys fid1@ser2.pub
    Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser2.nam.net|156.154.15.2|ser5.nam.net|156.154.18.6|ser6.nam.net|156.154.18.7|ser7.nam.net|156.154.18.8"

Comment: @DragonJana, it's hard to understand your comment. The 1st entry in your comment was not substituted

Comment: **Is that possible grep with only on middle entry ser2.nam.net on file and update like below**

Comment: _before ==>_

   Keys fid1@ser2.pub
    Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="**ser2.nam.net**|156.154.15.2|ser5.nam.net|156.154.18.6"

Comment: ,_after ==>_
 Keys fid1@ser2.pub
    Options command="eval $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",allow-from="ser2.nam.net|156.154.15.2|ser5.nam.net|156.154.18.6|ser6.nam.net|156.154.18.7|ser7.nam.net|156.154.18.8"

Comment: @DragonJana, ok, see my update